# Passing parameters to Pig script with HDInsight

Tags: apache-pig, azure-hdinsight

I'm using the HDInsight install of Hadoop on Windows, and trying to pass parameters to a pig script. I've used a couple of scripts on different machines, so I think it might be a Windows thing. I've put in default values to check the parameters work within the script

Example script:

```
%default myParam 'foo'
load('$myParam');
```

running as a dry run from the command line to test :
pig -r testSub.pig

results in:

```
load('foo');
```

but trying to supply the value from the command line:

```
pig -p myParam=bar -r testSub.pig
```

throws an error:

```
2013-04-23 13:37:27,531 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.Main - ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. Encountered unexpected arguments on command line - please check the command line.
Details at logfile: C:\Hadoop\hadoop-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT\logs\pig_1366720647495.log
```

and the logfile says the same:

```
Error before Pig is launched
----------------------------
ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. Encountered unexpected arguments on command line - please check the command line.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Encountered unexpected arguments on command line - please check the command line.
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:500)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:111)
================================================================================
```

I've tried using "-param", putting things in single and double quotes, moving the order around, but no luck. Any ideas what to try next - is there some weird escaping I need to add on Windows command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Your -p arguments are fine. You need to specify `-x local -r -f <file>`, eg:

`> pig -p myParam=bar -x local -r -f testSub.pig`

The `-x local` flag instructs pig to run locally without a mapreduce cluster.

Comment: thanks Ian, but it still has the same problem. I also need the real script to run on the cluster, but I think the problem is in the Pig parser via the Windows Command Window, not the where the script runs afterwards - it never gets that far

Comment: @TobyEvans did you find a solution to this. I am having the same issue on Windows

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same issue since the 0.4 release of HDInsight (March 25). I have also verified the scripts by putting parameter values directly in the script (working fine). Hence, it is probably a "windows" thing. One workaround is to place your parameters in a parameter file (myparamfile.txt) and reference that with:

```
    > pig -f testsub.pig -m myparamfile.txt
```